# Creating Databases and Tables using SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I have used `SQLIte3` to create `databases` and then added `tables` to it. Then i closed the `terminal` and reopened it.

I typed the command `sqlite3`, and typed `select * from tableName;` It says the table is not found.

Think i have to select the `database` first and then type the above `select` statement to work. So how can i do that ?

SQL commands like `show databases;` is not recognized.

Comment: See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180895/edit-sqlite-file-from-terminal-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write `sqlite3 DB_NAME` on terminal to open database. Then you can see sqlite prompt like `sqlite3>` You can enter command `select * from tableName` there, so that your tables will be listed. You can also try `.schema` command to see the schema of your data base. Refer the site http://www.sqlite.org/ for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SQLite Manager firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to view sqlite `database`, `table` and execute `query` there.